# jQuery Slideshow that supports a table format?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, slideshow, cycle

I have a client who has a website using CommerceSpace by Network Solutions and would like to have an image fader on the front page. The only issue I run into is I cannot seem to get it to work right because the formatting is in a table. That can't be changed because that's the way this software lays everything out. Does anybody have an idea? I would like to use the jQuery Cycle plugin, but I cannot get it to work right. Help?

It was working with scriptaculous before, but we didn't decide to use that due to jQuery working better for us, and this is what worked before.

```
var e2; var f2; var g2;
activeImage = 2; paused=0; 

if (document.getElementsByClassName('specials')[0] && document.getElementById('ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList')) {
trs = document.getElementById('ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList').getElementsByTagName('tr');
featcount = 0; colcount = 1;
for (i=0;i<trs.length;i++) { 
    if (trs[i].className == "nojs") { continue; }
    featcount++; trs[i].id="featimg"+featcount; 
    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td'); tdnum = 0;
    timeout = "new Effect.Parallel([";

    for (j=0;j<tds.length;j++) { 
        if (tds[j].className == "nojs") { continue; }
        tds[j].id=trs[i].id+"td"+tdnum;
        if (tds[j].getElementsByTagName('div')[0]) {
            tds[j].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id = tds[j].id+"div";
            if (featcount != activeImage) {
                tds[j].style.display='none'; 
                new Effect.Opacity(tds[j].id+"div", {from: 1, to:0, duration: 0});
            }
        }
        tdnum++; 
    }
}
function changeimg(direction,paused) {
    clearTimeout(e2);clearTimeout(f2);clearTimeout(g2);
    for3 = ""; for1 = "";
    oldImage = activeImage;
    if (direction=='previous'){activeImage = (activeImage == 1) ? featcount : activeImage-1;}
    else { activeImage = (activeImage >= featcount) ? 1 : activeImage+1;}

    timeout = "new Effect.Parallel([";
    for (i=0;i<colcount;i++) { timeout+="new Effect.Opacity('featimg"+oldImage+"td"+i+"div', {from: 1, to:0, duration: .5})"; if ((i+1)<colcount) { timeout+=","; }
    }
    e2 = setTimeout(timeout+"], {duration: 0, sync: true})",10);

    timeout = "new Effect.Parallel([";
    for (i=0;i<colcount;i++) { timeout+="new Effect.Fade('featimg"+oldImage+"td"+i+"', {duration: 0}),";}
    for (i=0;i<colcount;i++) { timeout+="new Effect.Appear('featimg"+activeImage+"td"+i+"', {duration: 0})"; if ((i+1)<colcount) { timeout+=","; }
    }
    f2 = setTimeout(timeout+"], {duration: 0, sync: true})",600);

    timeout = "new Effect.Parallel([";
    for (i=0;i<colcount;i++) { timeout+="new Effect.Opacity('featimg"+activeImage+"td"+i+"div', {from: 0, to:1, duration: 1})"; if ((i+1)<colcount) { timeout+=","; }
    }
    g2 = setTimeout(timeout+"], {duration: 0, sync: true})",700);

    if (direction=='auto' && paused==0) {t=setTimeout("changeimg('auto',"+paused+")",10000);}
    else {(pause(0))};
}
var t=setTimeout("changeimg('auto',0)",7000);
```

}

This is the general format of the table.

```
<table id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList" class="product-list" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td class="product-list-item-container" style="width:100%;">
<div class="product-list-item" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl00_imbAdd')">
<div class='caption_wrapper' style='float:left; width:240px;'>
<a href="/antiqueancient3000yearoldegyptiancarnelianstone-7-1-4-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-3-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-9.aspx">
<img class='product-list-img' src='/images/products/thumb/85caacopy.png' title='' style='width:240px; height:315px; border:none;' border='0' />
</a>
<div class='caption_description'>
<div class='caption_description_content' style='width:220px;'>
<p class="caption-title">  Large Ancient    Egyptian New Kingdom Clear Glass Bead 1500 BC. </p>

<p class="caption-price" style="padding-top:10px;">$28.00</p>
<p style="padding-top:10px; margin-left:-3px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl00$imbAdd" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl00_imbAdd" src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_add.gif" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl00$imbAdd&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;productList1739&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /><a href="/antiqueancient3000yearoldegyptiancarnelianstone-7-1-4-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-3-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-9.aspx"><img src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_view.gif" style="margin-top:-31px; margin-left:118px;"></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="product-list-item-container-alt" style="width:100%;">
<div class="product-list-item" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl01_imbAdd')">

<div class='caption_wrapper' style='float:left; width:240px;'>
<a href="/antiqueancient3000yearoldegyptiancarnelianstone-7-1-4-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-3-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-6.aspx">
<img class='product-list-img' src='/images/products/thumb/82caacopy.png' title='' style='width:240px; height:315px; border:none;' border='0' />
</a>
<div class='caption_description'>
<div class='caption_description_content' style='width:220px;'>
<p class="caption-title">  Large Ancient Egyptian New Kingdom Clear Glass Bead 1500 BC.</p>
<p class="caption-price" style="padding-top:10px;">$28.00</p>
<p style="padding-top:10px; margin-left:-3px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl01$imbAdd" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl01_imbAdd" src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_add.gif" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl01$imbAdd&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;productList1736&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /><a href="/antiqueancient3000yearoldegyptiancarnelianstone-7-1-4-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-3-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-6.aspx"><img src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_view.gif" style="margin-top:-31px; margin-left:118px;"></a></p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="product-list-item-container" style="width:100%;">
<div class="product-list-item" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl02_imbAdd')">
<div class='caption_wrapper' style='float:left; width:240px;'>
<a href="/antiqueancient3000yearoldegyptiancarnelianstone-7-1-4-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-3-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2.aspx">
<img class='product-list-img' src='/images/products/thumb/91caacopy.png' title='' style='width:240px; height:315px; border:none;' border='0' />
</a>
<div class='caption_description'>

<div class='caption_description_content' style='width:220px;'>
<p class="caption-title"> ANCIENT        EGYPTIAN    NEW   KINGDOM   MAGICAL GLASS   BEAD     1500 BC  </p>
<p class="caption-price" style="padding-top:10px;">$24.00</p>
<p style="padding-top:10px; margin-left:-3px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl02$imbAdd" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl02_imbAdd" src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_add.gif" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl02$imbAdd&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;productList1720&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /><a href="/antiqueancient3000yearoldegyptiancarnelianstone-7-1-4-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-3-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2.aspx"><img src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_view.gif" style="margin-top:-31px; margin-left:118px;"></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr><tr>

<td class="product-list-item-container-alt" style="width:100%;">
<div class="product-list-item" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl03_imbAdd')">
<div class='caption_wrapper' style='float:left; width:240px;'>
<a href="/rareashantibraceletc1880africanartantiquebracelet-scabra6-1-1-1.aspx">
<img class='product-list-img' src='/images/products/thumb/45caacopy.png' title='' style='width:240px; height:315px; border:none;' border='0' />
</a>
<div class='caption_description'>
<div class='caption_description_content' style='width:220px;'>
<p class="caption-title">  RARE   ASHANTI  BRACELET C1880 </p>
<p class="caption-price" style="padding-top:10px;">$120.00</p>

<p style="padding-top:10px; margin-left:-3px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl03$imbAdd" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl03_imbAdd" src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_add.gif" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl03$imbAdd&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;productList1714&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /><a href="/rareashantibraceletc1880africanartantiquebracelet-scabra6-1-1-1.aspx"><img src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_view.gif" style="margin-top:-31px; margin-left:118px;"></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="product-list-item-container" style="width:100%;">
<div class="product-list-item" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl04_imbAdd')">
<div class='caption_wrapper' style='float:left; width:240px;'>

<a href="/antiqueancient3000yearoldegyptiancarnelianstone-7-1-4-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-3-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1.aspx">
<img class='product-list-img' src='/images/products/thumb/86caacopy.png' title='' style='width:240px; height:315px; border:none;' border='0' />
</a>
<div class='caption_description'>
<div class='caption_description_content' style='width:220px;'>
<p class="caption-title">    ANCIENT    EGYPTIAN    NEW KINGDOM   MAGICAL GLASS   BEAD   1500 BC</p>
<p class="caption-price" style="padding-top:10px;">$24.00</p>
<p style="padding-top:10px; margin-left:-3px;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl04$imbAdd" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_productList_ctl04_imbAdd" src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_add.gif" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$productList$ctl04$imbAdd&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;productList1697&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" /><a href="/antiqueancient3000yearoldegyptiancarnelianstone-7-1-4-1-1-1-1-1-1-4-3-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1.aspx"><img src="/themes/barclay-1-2-1/images/buttons/cart_btn_view.gif" style="margin-top:-31px; margin-left:118px;"></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<table>`'s don't cooperate very well with the functionality needed for an image slideshow. `<div>`'s are a better fit. One option is to write JS code that morphs the table into a div so that the jQuery Cycle plug-in works. Have you considered this? Also, if there is an image in each `<td>`, I'm sure you could just write some simple jQuery to hide/show/animate on a timer or navigation basis. How much work are you trying to have us do here? Tell you what, if you can post some HTML and CSS, I will do a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for ya :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have javascript write out a div with your images.

```
document.write('<div class = "slideshow1">');
$('.product-list-img').each( function() { 
    document.write('<img src="'+this.src+'">') 
});
document.write('</div>')

window.onload= function() {
  $('.slideshow1').cycle({
        fx:       'fade',
        speed:     1500,
        timeout:   4000,
        next:      'slideshow1'
    });
};
```